# Logging QML errors in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, qt, qml

I'm trying to put in log QML errors in readable format.
I induce an error like this in my qml file

```
Connections {
    target: ыва
    function onSomeFunc() {
          
    }
}
```

and in Visual Studio 2019 (x64) i got the next output
`qrc:/SomePage.qml:104:5: QML Connections: ������� �onSomeFunc� �������� � �������� Connections. ��������, �� ������������ ��� ��������� ��������, �� �� ���� �� �������� ���� �� ������������� �����. qrc:/SomePage.qml:105: ReferenceError: ыва is not defined`

i tried to put this error in a file with this code

```
connect(engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::warnings, this, [](QList<QQmlError> const& warnings) {
        auto path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation) + "/logs/qmlerrors.txt";
        QFile file(path);
        if (file.open(QIODevice::Append))
        {
            QTextStream out(&file);
            for (auto warn : warnings)
            {
                out << warn.toString();
            }
        }
    });
```

but i got the same output with the unreadable symbols...
What am i missing? What do i have to do to print the humanreadable output?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you a 1C programmer? I assume that non-Latin characters are not allowed as attributes. Besides that you have to set an appropriate encoding using [QTextStream::setEncoding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextstream.html#setEncoding)

Comment: no, not 1C programmer, i know that they are not allowed, i was trying to induce that type of error.

Comment: more over i tried for encoding QStringConverter::Utf16, QStringConverter::Utf8 - this is the default one.. no luck whatsoever...

Comment: You are just appending strings to a textfile. It's difficult to determine from your code fragment what created encoding your textfile is in. Say, for example, your text file was Utf8 there is no evidence that you have the Utf8 BOM mark present. Also, I am not sure what the connection your code fragment is to Visual Studio 2019. If you are running it inside the Visual Studio Debugger, you shouldn't need all this messing around with QTextStream. All debug messages including errors should automatically appear in the debug view.

Comment: Append doesn't matter in this case, i tried to recreat the file from scratch - same output.

Comment: Debug messages do appear in the debug view in the same unreadable manner, i put this output into the file to be able to check what is happening on a customer side. And yes, i use the proper logging, this is just an example.